# ASP.NET 'Friendly URL' module - not working for root URL

Tags: asp.net, friendly-url

I am successfully using the 'Friendly URL' module in ASP.NET 4.5

In route config I can add a route like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("mypage", "mypage/{mypageName}", "~/mypage.aspx");
```

for a URL like this:

mysite.com/mypage/hello

in the page 'mypage.aspx' I can get URL segments like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls;

// Get URL segments
IList<string> segments = Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments();
if (segments.Count > 0)
{
    // Get first segment
    string url = segments[0];



}
```

However, I cannot get this working for root URL's. e.g. 'my site.com/ttee'

I want to get 'ttee' and pass it into a page. But 'Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments()' returns 0 for the root.

How best can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
routes.MapPageRoute("mypage", "mypage/{mypageName}", "~/mypage.aspx");
```

This will work only for URLs in this format:

```
www.example.com/mypage/changingparthere
```

If you want to make it

```
www.example.com/changablemypage
```

Set it to:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("mypage", "{mypageName}", "~/mypage.aspx");
```

But as you can see, it will catch literally everything. So make sure it is the last routing on Global.asax.

Comment: Thanks. How best do I get the value of {mypageName} in the page I use?

Comment: You don't need that friendly urls. Just write string url=RouteData.Values["mypageName"].ToString();

Comment: The key thing here is: IList<string> segments = Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments(); > this works for non-routed 'friendly' URL's and this is what you need for routed ones: url=RouteData.Values["mypageName"].ToString();